# Can't Figure Out Why MVC View is not passing values to the action in Firefox Browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Action in the controller:

```
public JsonResult ChangeGrowerTrainingDate(long growerId)
{
    //Do something   
}
```

View:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ChangeGrowerTrainingDate", "Grower", null, new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "TrainingDateChanged" }, new {@class=applicant.Id }))
{
   Html.Hidden("growerId", applicant.Id)
   //More stuff
}
```

I cannot figure out why "growerId" is not being passed from view to the action in the controller and problem happens only in Firefox in all other browsers everything works fine. Even works in IE.

Comment: I suspect the issue is something else? As the code you have supplied is all server side. Meaning it doesn't matter which browser you use it will all execute the same on the server. Are you using Cookies or Sessions anywhere and have cookies disabled in firefox. Or possibly JavaScript is disabled in firefox? Check the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out, because html was not passing proper syntax validation, firefox was closing form tag before  hidden input. Here is what I had and what caused the problem:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm(......)) 
{
 <tr><td>@Html.Hidden("growerId", aplicant.Id)</td></tr> 
}
```

FireFox was rendering it as:

```
 <form action="" method="post"></form>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="growerId" /></td></tr>
```

As we can see FireFox was closing form tag as soon as it opened it when it was rendering HTML and my hidden input was outside of the form, that is why nothing was getting submitted to the action in the controller.

I fixed it by moving my form into TD tag:

```
<tr><td>
  @using(Html.BeginForm(......)) 
  {
    @Html.Hidden("growerId", aplicant.Id)
  }
</td></tr>
```

And that fixed the issue.

Comment: This is not really an answer, in fact you only tell us what caused the problem. Did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. This is probably because `<form>` tags aren't allowed inside a `<td>` tag. You might want to accept your answer since it solved the problem.